# symfony2 access test environment by subdomain?

Tags: symfony

I'm looking for a way to expose my test environment via a subdomain. Basically, I want to do the equivalent of the console --env "test" via URL. So someone accessing http://example.com will get the production site, but the external testers can go to http://test.example.com and will get the test environment, with test database and everything.

I thought just using `SetEnv ENV "test"` in my apache config would do the trick, but apparently it doesn't.

I'm fairly sure this is a pretty common thing, so can someone guide me to the solution?

Comment: Please show your virtual host configuration for http://test.example.com
Does test.example.com points to app_dev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really weird that you're trying to access test environment through url, but I'll guess you need some special configuration for WebTestCases.

You need to create `app_test.php` file in web directory, and boot kernel with 'test' environment parameter. To see how to do it, check out already available `app.php` and `app_dev.php` files.

After that, setup your apache to aim for `app_test.php` when you hit your url. Also have in mind that you will probably have to make apache ignore `.htaccess` because it will point it to `app.php`. You can do it using `AllowOverride None`.

Comment: That's a really simple and cool solution. Yes, using app_test.php as part of the url gives me everything I need and I don't even have to set up a new vhost. Excellent solution.